# Beltrami-Laplace operator for dilatation

Tags: differential-geometry

Two spherical caps with common boundary $x^2+y^2=1$ undergo dilatation from radius a to b $( 1<a <b) $... somewhat like a bubble gum.

Can someone explain how to use Beltrami-Laplace operator to describe the transformation between the two?